# In a Sims like reality, How would a jailer get young men to wear a sarong and undershirts for nightwear?

Tags: social-norms, clothing, prison

I am sorry if this sounds repetitive but I asked the precursor of this question here [What could be reasoning of male prison in VR world to only allow undershirt and sarong as nightwear to male prisoners](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/151036/what-could-be-reasoning-of-male-prison-in-vr-world-to-only-allow-undershirt-and?noredirect=1#comment474516_151036)

Now I just wanted to know how would a jailer get young male prisoners less than age 30 to adopt a sarong and undershirts as nightwear?

Please remember these young men belong to cultures where a sarong or its variants are already worn by the older men. But younger men for sake of fashion and image prefer lowers, bottoms or pajamas. The jail has kept sarong and undershirts as nightwear because it's cheap, it's humiliating as only elderly or poor wear it, etc.
This question is more abt how the guy is talked to wear sarong

Comment: I really don't understand what the VR/sims part of your question means. If these are theoretical questions about how you personally are going to design a game, then it's not actually relevant to the question and is just going to cause confusion for people trying to answer.

Comment: Just trying to develop some game like thing . I m from southeast Asia.

Comment: Is your real question: "How do I persuade my players to keep on playing if their characters are forced to look unattractive?"

Comment: No. More like just a little strange part of a larger game.

Comment: Prisoners don't adopt orange suits in the USA either. That's given to them, so that's what they wear. Period! In prison, the fashion is uniformity and dictated by the laws or the chief warden. Also, VR or SIM has nothing to do with it. That's the setting, so unless hacked, it's the universal law. Period.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. Sorry

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, explain the difference between a VR and a sim-like reality

Comment: VR or virtual reality is more abt witnessing virtual reality as a witness while Sims is more like game

Comment: It's not a duplicate because one question is about why a prison would have this nightwear and the other is about how to get the prisoners to go along with it.  The not explaining Sims vs VR and what the rules are for answers is a completely separate problem.

Comment: Thanks for supporting me Cyn

Comment: Whether this is a duplicate or not, it feels Primarily Opinion Based to me either way.

Comment: You're welcome.  But honestly, they aren't the strongest questions.  I answered them because answers popped into my head (I try to answer as many questions as possible if I have something to say others haven't already said).  Good luck with your game though.

Comment: @Sikh and ye shall find, why do you care if prisoners "go along with it"?  Prisoners don't get a choice what they wear.

Comment: Whether the query is duplicate or not, I just don't understand what the foundation of your questions is.  I don't know where in SEA you're from, but Asia is the sarong capital of the universe.  It's like wearing britches in Europe or America. It's a matter of culture, and that is a typical article of clothing (as are shorts).  As far as prison is concerned, whatever is handed to the new inmate is going to be what he wears while inside.  My limited perspective on Asian prisons seems to indicate that inmates wear whatever clothing they brought in with them, be that shorts or sarong or whatever.

Answer (score 9):

### It's jail.  You don't need another reason.

They will wear them because they have to.

Because they aren't provided with other sleepwear.

Because they get punished for sleeping in their day clothing or for going naked at night.

The jailers tell prisoners what to do.  That's how prison works.  You don't have to convince anyone of anything.

Comment: Ya I can imagine the conversation between jailer and young dude to be like. Jailer : "so what nightwear do u wear?" , Guy : "jockey shorts" , jailer : "no more dude". *Hands him over a lungi and vest. I guess most young male characters would be shocked and embarrassed

Comment: Young Male Character: I can't wear this!  It's shocking and embarrassing!  Jailer: *Doesn't care, doesn't provide any other options, shoves prisoner in cell.  It's jail.  The opinion of the prisoners is irrelevant.

Comment: Young male prisoner comes outside his cell in a sarong and undershirt after sometime. Initially he dislikes it , but soon gets used to it. And some will continue wearing them even after leaving prison because they begun to like it's airy comfort.